# Google Chrome: persist devtools setting per site

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

Is it possible to get Google Chrome's Devtools to apply the "Rendering" feature "Enable automatic dark mode" automatically, for a given list of websites?

One potential problem is that, even when you go ahead and manually toggle "Enable automatic dark mode", after a while, it will cease to work, even as the box remains checked.

To be clear, I'm in Dark Mode already, and this is for sites that don't support the usual Dark Mode.

Comment: What platform are we talking about? For example, Android has its own rules on darkmode

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if there is a way to do it through chrome dev tool. though, there's an extension in chrome [store](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/category/extensions) I used to use it, [Dark Mode](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/dark-mode/dmghijelimhndkbmpgbldicpogfkceaj).

The extension can work for all sites, specific sites or active on press.
You can also set your own colors in the dark mode, the background color, text color, link color, cite color and visited link color. you can also customize the behavior of converting the websites elements like SVG's, images, icons, and other elements. And you can write your own CSS code for more customizing.

And there's many pre-made themes to choose from.

I found it very useful for eye relief when spending a long time behind the screen.